# How to Create & Add new object in existing array using Dynamic Memory allocation

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to do some stuff with C++ and i am new in it :)

I have tried 1 program of class that gets the student details and print the output of it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 10

class student
{
    private:
        char  name[30];
        int   rollNo;
        int   total;
        float perc;
    public:
        //member function to get student's details
        void getDetails(void);
        //member function to print student's details
        void putDetails(void);
};

//member function definition, outside of the class
void student::getDetails(void){
    cout << "Enter name: " ;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter roll number: ";
    cin >> rollNo;
    cout << "Enter total marks outof 500: ";
    cin >> total;
    perc=(float)total/500*100;
}

//member function definition, outside of the class
void student::putDetails(void) {
    cout << "Student details:\n";
    cout << "Name:"<< name << ",Roll Number:" << rollNo << ",Total:" << total << ",Percentage:" << perc;
}

int main()
{
    student std[MAX];       //array of objects creation
    int n,loop;

    cout << "Enter total number of students: ";
    cin >> n;

    for(loop=0;loop< n; loop++){
        cout << "Enter details of student " << loop+1 << ":\n";
        std[loop].getDetails();
    }

    cout << endl;

    for(loop=0;loop< n; loop++) {
        cout << "Details of student " << (loop+1) << ":\n";
        std[loop].putDetails();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its very basic code and works fine and I am able to give inputs and print the output.

Now I want to add new Student object at runtime using Dynamic memory allocation and want to add that object in the existing array of object (So that I can get the highest, lowest marks of any student)

> I know I need to use `new` operator for this.

But I am not sure what could be the best way to write this solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You usually don't use `new` or `delete` operations manually in your code with c++.. Also such declarations as raw `student std[MAX];` arrays aren't used in production code. You have standard container classes and smart pointers at hand to deal with dynamic memory allocation, Just use these,

Comment: I am not looking for production at the moment. The code that i have attached is kind of 1 program, and my another task is to modify the above program and add dynamic memory allocation in it.

Comment: _"another task is to modify the above program and add dynamic memory allocation in it"_ The essence of my comment is that you shouldn't do that yourself, but simply use the standard c++ facilities which do that in 1st place. Using `new` or `delete` in your own code is the really really last resort to solve very special and advanced problems.

Comment: `student std[MAX];` Don't do that! Use a `std::vector<student> std;` instead. There's no need to use raw arrays in c++.

Comment: *I know I need to use new operator for this* -- Wrong.  There is no need for `new` to accomplish this.  Then this: `char  name[30];` -- Buffer overflow if I input more than 30 characters,  use `std::string` instead.  Then of course, this one that so many new programmers get wrong:  `student std[MAX];` -- Invalid C++.  Overall, it seems as if you're not learning C++, but actually `C` with a few C++ syntax thrown in.

Comment: Thank you everyone for giving me such grateful pieces of information. I will continue further on it and will update with the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, The best way to do this using dynamic memory is by using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (it actually depends on the requirement).

Here is one example of usage of `unique_ptr`:

```
using StudentPtr = std::unique_ptr<student>;

int main() {
    std::vector<StudentPtr> studentDetails;
    int n;

    cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> n;

    studentDetails.resize(n);

    for (auto &s: studentDetails) {
        s = StudentPtr(new student);
        s->getDetails();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For getting minimum and maximum, you may use `min_element` and `max_element` provided by STL respectively.

Comment: @JayeshDhandha If you feel this answered your question, consider voting and accepting https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers